# If a sentence starts with an 'a' should the 'a' be capitalised?

Tags: capitalization

If you were to start a sentence with an 'a' would it be capitalised? Because when an 'a' is on its own its lower case. But letters at the start of sentences should be capitalised.

Comment: What do you mean by "an 'a'"? Are you talking about the indefinite article, like in a sentence like "A book was on the table"? You certainly would capitalize that.

Comment: "Because when an 'a' is on its own its lower case." says who?

Comment: Except for proper nouns, all words on their own are uncapitalized except when they're at the beginning of a sentence. Why do you think there would be an exception for *a*?

Comment: What do you mean Kris? Obviously when you write an 'a' in the middle of a sentence it is lowercase

Comment: @Barmar Well, a beginner English learner might wonder because not  'all words on their own are uncapitalized except when they're at the beginning of a sentence', in fact. For example, I might cite the word at the end of this sentence, mightn't I?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You answered your own question, but I will paraphrase what you wrote slightly:

> The first letter at the start of a sentence should be capitalized.

It just so happens that the first letter of the word **a** is **a**.

---

There are some additional style guidelines that apply:

- Don't start a sentence with a numeral.
- Don't start a sentence with a symbol. (With the exception of a contracted word that uses an apostrophe.)
- Don't start a sentence with a proper noun that is explicitly lowercase.

In other words, you should always try to rephrase a sentence so that it starts with a word (or name)—and its first letter should be capitalized.

So, change:

> k.d. lang was on stage tonight.

To, for example:

> On stage tonight was k.d. lang.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Even if a sentence begins with the indefinite article, it *must* be capitalized; e.g.

> "[**A** funny thing happened](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=bRdPW7zuJIzw_wSFgLCwDA&q=%22A+funny+thing+happened%22&oq=%22A+funny+thing+happened%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1l4j0l6.19446.21452.0.24336.9.9.0.0.0.0.256.1510.0j1j6.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.7.1506...0i7i30k1j0i13k1.0.HEQ0gY5uNnE) to me the other day. I was going to…"

And

> [**An** apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple) is a sweet, edible fruit produced by an apple tree (Malus pumila).

Comment: Well, "must" is pretty strong.  There's nothing that *must* be done in English, just "accepted practices".